# How best to intercept ASPX call to codebehind class?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a compiled .NET web app with a Login.aspx that sets username / password string values in a codebehind class then fires an OnClick Page event to perform authentication.
Now, I need to add an extra level of authentication, so I need to intercept this call, passing the credentials to my class in my assembly, then conditionally passing them on to the existing class / assembly.

How best to do this? Note, the codebehind class is compiled so I don't have the code to be able to change it there, however I do have the Login.aspx.

I am a noob to .NET web apps so I'm not sure where to start. I expect to have to rewrite the Login.aspx or replace it with MVC, use jQuery to conditionally set the codebehind, or something....not sure. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your "OnClick Page event" is a button click handler, here's what you can do:

Create a new class that inherits from the codebehind class that you have:

```
public class MyAuthForm : WebForm1
{
}
```

(where WebForm1 is the name of the compiled class - probably "Login" or something similar in your case.)

Then add an overwrite of the Click event in that class:

```
public class MyAuthForm : WebForm1
{
   protected new void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      // do your stuff

      base.Button1_Click(sender, e);    
   }
}
```

Change the code in Login.aspx to use the new class you just created:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyAuthForm.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.MyAuthForm" %>
```

This should intercept the button click event and give you a possibility to handle it before passing it on to the original click event in your compiled codebehind class.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I should have thought of that tho. *facepalm*